# How To fix CORS Error In ASP.Net Core API 5 and VUE

Tags: vue.js, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

I've set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * , in server response, but I get CORS Error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'api.ghazalahmadi.com/api/Account/SendCode' from origin 'ghazalahmadi.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

[image: Request+Response Preflight]

Comment: What is the actual error that the browser shows you?

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://api.ghazalahmadi.com/api/Account/SendCode' from origin 'http://ghazalahmadi.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Comment: 'api.ghazalahmadi.com/api/Account/SendCode' work in postman correctly

Comment: all Get Methods is working correctly

Comment: Postman isn't a good tool to debug CORS issues as it doesn't enforce CORS or even send the preflight request that seems to be returning a non 2xx status code.

Comment: CORS is implemented by modern browsers but the change to allow CORS requests must be made on the backend.  your frontend origin 'ghazalaahmadi.com' must be set as an allowed origin.  [Here](https://blog.logrocket.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-enabling-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors/) is a lot of good general information about CORS. For .NET core 5 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0) are the specific framework instructions.

Comment: The inner error-message says: _"Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: **It does not have HTTP ok status**."_ (emphasis mine) - which means your browsers' `OPTIONS` preflight request failed - I guess it returned a HTTP 500 response, perhaps? Please share the request+response details of the preflight request.

Comment: image uploaded above

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.